# How can I make sure only my browser uses flash?

Tags: flash, dll, memory-leaks, data-execution-prevention

I don't want dumb stuff like this to happen, causing MSN Messenger to take 1.5 GB:

[image]

How can I make sure that only my browser is able to run Flash?

Comment: Routing around the problem: use an alternative MSN client.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is a way to actually do this, because MSN might come with an own flash installation or may prompt to download flash if it is not installed.

What you could do however, in case you are using `Chrome` or you are willing to switch to it: Simply uninstall Flash as `Chrome` comes with integrated Flash

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need it anywhere else, uninstall the ActiveX version of Flash Player. Modern browsers (except IE 9) use the NPAPI version, which can be installed independently.

edit:
Looking at the file name, the messenger probably is shipped with a separate version of Flash Player so my answer might have no effect. In this case try to unregister (and rename) the given file. Warning: this might break functionality of the messenger.